# Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 while using a generic class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm getting a "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11" error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
<unknown>:0: error: swift frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have narrowed it down to this class:

```
class WSObjectDto<T> : AuthenticationResponseDto {

    var Object: T?        
}
```

When `var Object: T?` is commented out the project compiles just fine. Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong here to cause the Segmentation fault?

UPDATE:
It also builds fine if I don't inherit from AuthenticationResponseDto.

```
class AuthenticationResponseDto : NSObject {

    var TokenAuthenticated = false
    var WSConnectionFailed = false
    var WSThrewException = false
    var JsonParserException = false
    var AppVersionNotSupported = false
}
```

Comment: What is `AuthenticationResponseDto`?

Comment: Also, what version of Swift / Xcode is this?

Comment: @matt I posted the 'AuthenticationResponseDto' class. Swift 1.2 Xcode 6.4.

Comment: Still can't reproduce the problem based on what you've said. Please try updating to Xcode 7 beta 3 and see if the issue goes away for you. Thanks!

Comment: A generic subclass of a nongeneric superclass might be what's giving the Swift parser trouble here, but I believe you'll find the issue is fixed in Xcode 7. If not, something else is going on that you haven't told us about yet.

Comment: @matt Thanks for looking into it! I just made the switch to `var Object: AnyObject?` and it all works fine. Just wondering what was going wrong with the generic way.

Comment: Since I can't crash, I've no idea. Your code compiles just fine for me.

Comment: Probably be hard for anyone to reproduce without full project available....